# Self-hosted Doodle.com alternative

Tags: web-apps, survey

I love(d) to use [Doodle.com](http://doodle.com/) where I can create items (dates, or maybe movies) and let other people vote on them (as in: Mr X is available on these dates but not on that one). It just makes creating appointments with others way easier.

Is there an (open source preferably) alternative that I can install on my own server? In a post-Snowden world I’d like to keep as much of my data under my control.

Comment: What do you mean with "dates, or maybe movies" when creating an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could most likely use the aptly named "Dudle", which is open source under AGPL Version 3.

https://dudle.inf.tu-dresden.de/about.cgi

Comment: Thanks, that looks very good indeed. Seems very unclear how to install though (at least for my pretty limited abilities) and Google doesn't find any reports/tutorials  for it either. So dear future, if you find this question and know about a step-by-step guide how to install Dudle - please leave a message.

Thanks, ZeroFlux!

Comment: Maybe try Clockworks as an alternative: https://sipb.mit.edu/projects/clockworks/

Comment: @ZeroFlux - that project doesn't seem to be publicly accessible - do you have a link to a download or repository?

Comment: @jmetz Unfortunately, no, I don't have any additional access information beyond what's available on those links. Although I haven't looked into either project for a few months, so a fresh Google might be warranted!

Comment: @ZeroFlux though this answer is upvoted and accepted, it doesn't really meet our [quality rules](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185). Could you please [edit] it and include how Dudle meets the OPs requirements, and what exactly makes it recommendable (personal experiences preferred ;)?

Comment: clockworks is available publicly (albeit awkwardly) at https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb.mit.edu/project/clockworks/clockworks.git/ - and after a very long slow `wget --mirror --no-parent ...` and then `find -name 'index.html*' -delete` and then `git clone ...` I learned that the project is a Python 2.x project using Django - about 30 git commits between 2009 and 2010, where the last commit is an update to TODO file with one of the items being "Care about security, at all." :-(

Answer (score 2):

[Framadate](https://framadate.org/) is worth a try. It meets all your requirements:

- It's Free Software released under the CeCILL-B License.
- It's "like Doodle"
- You can host it yourself.

[image: demo]

It is a fork of STUdS and used to be known under the name of OpenSondage. A downside of the project may be, that it is primarily managed in french.

The software is not packaged for common GNU/Linux distributions yet but you can install it through Sandstorm.

Comment: Can you specify why it's a "great tool for this"?  How does it meet the post requirements?

Comment: All the requirements of the question are met. "like doodle", free software (open source) and you can host it yourself. I just felt I'd have to write a full sentence. Actually "Framadate." would be the correct answer. ;)

Comment: Well, feelings are one thing – site rules another. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer: Why is it a "great tool"? How does it meet the requirements? Personal experiences (for the "why" part) are welcome. And please, don't put it in comments, but [edit] it into the answer itself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *Rallly* (three 'L's) to find an appointment date.
Currently it cannot be used for a non-calendar vote.
If you click on the demo you can also try the new beta interface.

https://rallly.co/
https://github.com/lukevella/Rallly