# Software for appointment scheduling multiple people

Tags: calendar, booking

I am looking for some software, similar to Calendly.com, where I can email people a link and they can select to book a meeting with me when I'm available, but I want this software to be able to analyze multiple people's calendars to look for availability. This is something Calendly does not do unless all those other people also are on your same calendly account. Ideally this would be free or inexpensive software, like Calendly.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10742/79100

Comment: You can try Zoho Bookings (https://www.zoho.com/bookings/), but I am not sure it can analyze calendars of multiple accounts